# How to return nothing/pop up box/stay on page with just a message "success" after post mapping?

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to return nothing after post mapping in Spring Boot?

I have this controller, that controller is connected with button, when button is pressed this controller will save a current element from collection into new collection.

```
 @PostMapping("/savedAdventureHolidays/post/{adventureHolidayId}")
public String saveAdventureHolidayElement(@PathVariable(value = "adventureHolidayId") String adventureHolidayId,
                                          Model model) {

    UserProfile comment = new UserProfile();

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();

    return adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(adventureHolidayId).map(post -> {
        comment.setAdventureHolidaysList(Collections.singletonList(post));
        comment.setLoggedUserId(username);
        comment.setSavedHolidayTitle(adventureHolidaysRepository.findById(adventureHolidayId).get().getTitle());
        model.addAttribute("comment", comment);
        userProfileRepository.save(comment);
        return "redirect:/adventureHolidays/randomSummerCamps";
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("PostId " + adventureHolidayId + " not found"));
}
```

As you can see I have here this return:

```
return "redirect:/adventureHolidays/randomSummerCamps";
```

But its always a different element in HTML since I have this method

```
@Override
public AdventureHolidays findRandomAdventureHolidays(String type) {
    if (elementsToReturn.size() == 0) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("typeOfAdventureHolidays").is(type));
        List<AdventureHolidays> newData = mongoTemplate.find(query, AdventureHolidays.class);
        Collections.shuffle(newData);
        elementsToReturn.addAll(newData);
    }
    return elementsToReturn.poll();
}
```

Comment: I don't think I completely understand the question... You want to return nothing to the caller of the api? so whatever caller makes the call to: /savedAdventureHolidays/post/{adventureHolidayId} should only receive the HttpStatus I guess? You can just let the method "saveAdventureHolidayElement" return void in that case.

Comment: But in all regards it's always better to return something. Even if it's just to make debugging easier from the other side. Like if you send data to an api, it's always good to get some sort of confirmation about the processing back. IMO

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain good what I want. As I said, I have a controller that return me a random element from collection, that works, then I have a save button that will save a current element that is provided in new entity, so after that post mapping, do nothing, just stay on that page, but what is the problem, when I try to return same page, its always another element from collection not the one that user saved previously,  you can check it on heroku (its not up to date) but you'll get it https://trip-advisor-app.herokuapp.com/api/auth/loginAndRegisterForm (user: admin) (pass: admin123)

Comment: Go on adventure holidays > summer camps, you will see button save doc, on that version that button is not working, BUT, on my local right now, when user click save, user should stay on same page with same element from collection while he is now getting another random element from collection

Comment: https://github.com/jankovicdev/TripAdvisorApp branch is feature/save-trips... you can check it there

Comment: I think it's more an issue in how you do calls from the front-end. Because in the java there's no issue it seems, you might want to save the trip in local storage or a cookie, and if the storage contains a trip then load that trip instead of calling the api to get the random trip. My apologies if not clear, I'm on secure connection so I can't do much right now. Maybe share front-end code? Maybe someone can help with that too.